# How to handle the request type is application/pdf in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

In jmeter for particular request i am getting the decoded response so not able to extract the data from that response,request type is application/pdf an even i changed content type as application/pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Jmeter response will remain in the same way you are getting it.

To validate your files, you can use "**Save Responses to a file**" Listener.

Hope this will help.

Comment: already i done the samething and even able to see the content in html  file which i mentioned in the save response file but i want to extract desired data from jmeter http sampler respose itself so let me know.

Comment: the only way to do that is, after the file is saved ... write your own code in Beanshell sampler to parse pdf file and extract the required data.